# Ruby Net::HTTP#ca_file seems no use

Tags: ruby, ssl, curl

My site uses a StartCom ssl certificate, which fails to be verified by ruby's Net::HTTP.
I set ruby's Net::HTTP#ca_file, but it still doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
irb(main):007:0> uri = URI('https://blog.a1ex.wang')
=> #<URI::HTTPS https://blog.a1ex.wang>
irb(main):008:0> h=Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)
=> #<Net::HTTP blog.a1ex.wang:443 open=false>
irb(main):009:0> h.use_ssl=true
=> true
irb(main):010:0> h.ca_file="/home/alexwang/keys/blog/ca.pem"
=> "/home/alexwang/keys/blog/ca.pem"
irb(main):011:0> h.start
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed
    from /home/alexwang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:933:in `connect_nonblock'
    from /home/alexwang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:933:in `connect'
    from /home/alexwang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
    from /home/alexwang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:858:in `start'
    from (irb):11
    from /home/alexwang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb(main):012:0>
```

But with curl, the SSL verification seems OK.

```
> curl "https://blog.a1ex.wang" -I
curl: (60) server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you\'d like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
[16:53:12] alexwang@alexwang-surbuntu /home/alexwang (60)                           
> curl "https://blog.a1ex.wang" --cacert keys/blog/ca.pem -I
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.9.3 (Ubuntu)
Date: Sun, 20 Mar 2016 08:53:18 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Link: <https://blog.a1ex.wang/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have all certificates in chain in `ca.pem`, not only root certificate. Your site has two authorities in chain:

- CN=StartCom Certification Authority
- CN=StartCom Class 1 DV Server CA

It worked if you I have both authorities in [ca.pem](https://gist.github.com/vitstradal/0c02bc4d32953c4f1a4d).

Comment: It still doesn't work with your ca.pem. I tried with ruby 2.3.0 and 1.9.3.

Comment: my ruby is 2.1.2p95 and this example works: https://gist.github.com/vitstradal/c57e263a07e467d8f5f4

Comment: Still doesn't work with your ca.pem and ruby 2.1.2. What is your operation system and openssl version?